# Restrict access of the back-end pool form application gateway public ip

Tags: azure-application-gateway

I have mapped the DNS of application gateway (v2) to the public domain registry and I am able to access the backend pool (web app) from the public domain (mydomain.com). But I am also able to access the web app from DNS/IP of application gateway.

I want to restrict the access of web app from the DNS/IP of application gateway.

thanks,
regards
Sakaldeep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to access the web app from the public domain (mydomain.com) but not from the  IP/DNS of application gateway, but still the traffic should go through application gateway (domain->App GW->Web App) then configure **Multi-site Listener** even you have only one site.

You will see below when you hit through IP/DNS of application gateway but still able to access through the domain. Also, configure restriction at the web app level.

[404 Not Found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgP65.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to access the web app only from the DNS/IP of application gateway. If so, you could add an access restriction rule to your web app.

You could open `Network`>`Access Restrictions` and click on `Configure Access Restrictions` in your app service on the Azure portal. Ref: [adding and editing Access Restriction rules in the portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions#adding-and-editing-access-restriction-rules-in-the-portal). You can click on [+] `Add` to add a 
front-end IP address of application gateway in the access restriction rule.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I want to access the web app only from my public domain (mydomain.com) not from the IP/DNS of application gateway but the request should go through application gateway (domain->app gw->web app). I have already done the restriction at web app level as you shown.

Comment: First, you need to use DNS records to map the public domain to your app GW FQDN or IP. You could remove the hostname of your public domain in web app service, then set `use for app service` in HTTP settings of application gateway.

Comment: it has already configured. Did you understand my question, what I want is when I hit IP/DNS of app gw in the browser it should be unreachable.

Comment: I see. this is impossible. If you have app gw in front of web app service, you could access the web app via app gw even you map a DNS to app GW, you're essentially accessing the backends via app gw frontend.

Comment: Ok, but while accessing using domain then https work fine but when i access through ip/dns of app gw it says unsure. what could be the issues.

Comment: It sounds like app gw has not configured well. What's your `backend health` status in your app GW? Make sure the public domain is pointed to app gw instead of web app service. https://digwebinterface.com/

Comment: backend health is good and the domain is pointed to app gw. I got the solution what i wanted. thanks.